# How to get the ID of GPU allocated to a SLURM job on a multiple GPUs node?

Tags: gpu, nvidia, slurm, sbatch

When I submit a SLURM job with the option --gres=gpu:1 to a node with two GPUs, how can I get the ID of the GPU which is allocated for the job? Is there an environment variable for this purpose? The GPUs I'm using are all nvidia GPUs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the GPU id with the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`. This variable is a comma separated list of the GPU ids assigned to the job.

Comment: It works. Thanks. It seems that the environment variable GPU_DEVICE_ORDINAL also works.

Comment: This doesn't identify the GPU uniquely when using cgroups. With cgroups, CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES would be 0 for all GPUs because each process only sees a single GPU (others are hidden by the cgroup).

Answer (score 5):

You can check the environment variables `SLURM_STEP_GPUS` or `SLURM_JOB_GPUS` for a given node:

```sh
echo ${SLURM_STEP_GPUS:-$SLURM_JOB_GPUS}
```

Note `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` may not correspond to the real value ([see @isarandi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967405/how-to-get-the-id-of-gpu-allocated-to-a-slurm-job-on-a-multiple-gpus-node/43968080#comment99711281_43968080)).

Also, note this should work for non-Nvidia GPUs as well.

Answer (score 3):

Slurm stores this information in an environment variable, `SLURM_JOB_GPUS`.

One way to keep track of such information is to log all SLURM related variables when running a job, for example (following [Kaldi](https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi)'s [slurm.pl](https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/blob/master/egs/wsj/s5/utils/parallel/slurm.pl), which is a great script to wrap Slurm jobs) by including the following command within the script run by `sbatch`:

```
set | grep SLURM | while read line; do echo "# $line"; done
```