# Can I look up the specific GPU that a completed Slurm job used?

Tags: gpu, slurm

Is it possible to determine which GPU a completed Slurm job used? I have seen from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967405/how-to-get-the-id-of-gpu-allocated-to-a-slurm-job-on-a-multiple-gpus-node) that you can get the ID of the GPU from within a currently running job, but I'm curious whether you can do it afterwards. I've tried `sacct --format==AllocGRES` and that just gives the number of allocated GPUs. I'm not seeing any other relevant fields.