# How do I know which GPUs a job was allocated using SLURM?

Tags: slurm

I can run a job on slurm with, for example, `srun --gpus=2` and it will set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to the GPUs allocated.  However I know of no such way to inspect which GPUs SLURM allocated a particular job.  If I run `scontrol show job` it will show me something like `TresPerJob=gpu:2` but it doesn't contain the actual GPUs allocated.

Where can I find this information?  In other words, how can I look up which GPUs job *n* was allocated?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the ID of GPU allocated to a SLURM job on a multiple GPUs node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967405/how-to-get-the-id-of-gpu-allocated-to-a-slurm-job-on-a-multiple-gpus-node)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for what slurm set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to, I'd suggest using `cat /proc/12345/environ` where the number is the PID of whatever slurm launched.

This is liable to be overridden, however, with something like `srun --export=ALL bash -i`, so you can't rely on it in the adversarial case.

Comment: I wrote a script that does just this: https://gist.github.com/schmmd/1aa445be858ce560d48e13ef2041fea1

Answer (score 12):

`scontrol show job -d` can do this.  The `-d` flag adds extra info to the output, one of which is a field like `GRES=gpu(IDX:0-2)`.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute `nvidia-smi` command, you get somethign like this:

[image]

The "GPU" column is the ID of the GPU which usually matches the device in the system (`ls /dev/nvidia*`). This same identification is used by Slurm in `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable. 
So, when in this variable you see

> 0,1,2

means that the job has been assigned with the GPUs whose IDs are 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: Yes, but it's possible someone overwrote their `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` and are using a GPU device that SLURM did not assigned.  `nvidia-smi` will not expose this.

Comment: Yes, it is a plausible scenario. Nevertheless, your question goes another way.

Comment: How do I get the process id for a particular job?

Comment: I found out I can get this with `sstat -i 9999999` (although, with a real job number).

Comment: you can't just run `nvidia-smi` on slurm. you need to be in a GPU node terminal.